# Como crear mi formulario de Login en laravel y no usar el que trae por defecto laravel

Tags: css, laravel

¿Que tal? Realizaré un formulario en laravel pero tengo la siguiente duda, si no quiero usar el que trae por defecto laravel, es decir laravel trae una tabla que se llama user y yo quiero que se llame Usuarios y mi llave primaria sea Usuario y contraseña Password, lo que yo quiero es que las letras empiecen con letra mayusculas podria hacer eso?¨cambiando mi tabla a Usuarios y con las columnas de Usuario y Password?

Que tendria que modificar para que quede como quiero?